# Spark worker got java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I was trying to learn Spark, so I used docker to setup a docker-compose with 1 master node and 2 workers using the latest image from Bitnami. The docker-compose I used was the one from bitnami github. Just some basic stuff, container_name, image, ports 7077 and 8080 for master, then add in master url for worker. The docker-compose up returned a success from the log and SparkUI also displayed 2 workers with correct CPU cores and RAM.

Then I start a Jupyter Notebook and successfully created a Session to the master node (Displayed on SparkUI).

The error came when I try to run anything with the Spark Session. The log from spark container returned that Executor got removed because of status EXITED, then it create a new Executor, which then it removed for the same reason. It kept doing so until I terminate the container.

I checked the Stderr from the EXITED Executor, the error displayed was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
.....
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
.....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to Jake/<unresolved>:57142
.....
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Jake
```

I have tried to find a different docker-compose from forums and the stackoverflow that seems to work fine for others, but no luck.

I have also tried deleting the hostname from docker-compose, but nothing changed.